# how to generate error when the field is empty by using express-validator in validationResult

Tags: validation, express, express-validator

I'm using express-validator.

I want to generate an error in validationResult if the field is empty.

This is my code:

```
router.post('/register',[
    check('name').isEmpty().withMessage('Name field cannot be empty.'),
    check('email').isEmail().withMessage('Enter valid email address.'),
    check('username').isEmpty().withMessage('Username cannot be empty.'),
    check('password').isEmpty().matches('password2').withMessage('Password dont match.')
], function(req, res, next) {

  const errors = validationResult(req);
  console.log(errors.array());

  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    res.render('register2',{
        errors: errors.mapped(), 
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        password2: req.body.password2
    });
  }
});
```

I want to generate error when name field and username field is empty but I only get errors for these fields:

```
[ { location: 'body',
param: 'email',
value: '',
msg: 'Enter valid email address.' },
{ location: 'body',
param: 'password',
value: '',
msg: 'Password dont match.' } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently doing opposite of what you want. When you do this:

```
check('username').isEmpty().withMessage('Username cannot be empty.'),
```

you want the username to be empty and are issuing an error if it's not. You can change it to:

```
check('username').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Username cannot be empty.'),
```

or:

```
check('username').exists().withMessage('Username cannot be empty.'),
```

instead.